# Flutter Textfield in a row with a DropdownButton has different height

Tags: flutter

[Error on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y5hW.png)

The Textfield Widget has other height than the dropdownbutton...

```
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: TextFormField(
                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                hintText: "Name",
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                                    MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width *
                                                        0.015),
                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                fillColor: contrastColor,
                                                hoverColor: contrastColor,
                                                focusColor: contrastColor,
                                                filled: true,
                                              ),
                                              maxLength: 20,
                                              onChanged: (value) {
                                                setState(() {});
                                              },
                                            ),
                                            flex: 4,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.001,
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: TextFormField(
                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                hintText: "Preis",
                                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                                    MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width *
                                                        0.015),
                                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                                fillColor: contrastColor,
                                                hoverColor: contrastColor,
                                                focusColor: contrastColor,
                                                filled: true,
                                              ),
                                              maxLength: 5,
                                              onChanged: (value) {
                                                setState(() {});
                                              },
                                            ),
                                            flex: 2,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.001,
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: InputDecorator(
                                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                fillColor: contrastColor,
                                                hoverColor: contrastColor,
                                                focusColor: contrastColor,
                                                filled: true,
                                              ),
                                              child: Expanded(
                                                child: DropdownButton(
                                                  dropdownColor: contrastColor,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: mainColor),
                                                  value: ,
                                                  items: [],
                                                  onChanged: (String? value) {
                                                    setState(() {},
                                                    );
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            flex: 4,
                                          ),
```

I tried fixing it and wrapping every Textfield in an Container, but it just smashed the complete Programm...

Textfield || Dropdownbutton -> Expanded -> Row -> Column

I need a way that all these Borders are exactly the same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this snippet you shared is pulled out from the *children* of a `Row` widget. I presume this because the linked image aligns them horizontally and the majority of widgets are `Expanded`.

If my presumptions are correct, then the following should help:

1. The `maxLength` property on the `TextFormField`s seem to occupy extra vertical space just below the input fields for the number of character used. Your screenshot doesn't capture that because maybe your background is black (matching with text color). You might want to change the black background to confirm this.
2. Now as you have relatively taller `TextFormField`s, the `DropdownButton` occupies a lesser vertical space and it is aligned to the center of the vertical axis (cross axis of the `Row`). This is the default. If I'm still on the right track, set the crossAxisAlignment property on the parent Row (that you didn't include in the snippet) to `CrossAxisAlignment.start`. This will take the `DropdownButton` upwards and align them as you want.
3. Play around `isCollapsed: true` and `isDense: true` on the properties of the `InputDecorator` of the `DropdownButton`. Combine them or use either of each. Equally test `contentPadding` and `constraints` properties. Those will work towards adjusting/reducing the vertical space of the `DropdownButton`.
4. On the other hand, you can also increase the padding of the `TextFormField`s to match the height of the `InputDecorator`.
5. Remove the `Expanded` that directly wraps the `DropdownButton`, it throws an error to Flutter logs. The error is because the parent of `Expanded` or `Flexible` must be a `Flex` (a Row or a Column). The parent `Expanded` of `InputDecorator` should be enough for that last dropdown section.

Comment: `maxLength` has no influence, I removed it. `isDense` and `isCollapsed` are changing the size, but not to the same as the TextFields

Comment: I used `contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),` on the `TextFormField` and `contentPadding:const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 9),` on `DropDownButtonFormField` that worked :)